# colocar una option como predeterminada en una lista desplegable con php

Tags: php, html

Hola a todos tengo una lista desplegable que se llena con datos de la BD pero quiero que al cargar la lista se coloque un valor predeterminado o selected.
verán tengo un form para editar un producto cuando abro el form me carga los datos del producto pero la categoría esta en un select (combobox) que se carga automáticamente al abrir el form, y quiero que aparezca seleccionada la opcion que el producto tenia pero que tambien pueda seleccionar cualquier otra.

este el el código para mostrar las categorías

```
   <?php  if (isset($verCategorias) && $verCategorias->num_rows > 0) { ?>
    
      <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
      <?php $sel = 2; //variable para probar
      while ($lista = $verCategorias->fetch_object()) {
     //con este codigo me muestra todas las categorias  
//echo '<option value="'.$lista->idCategoria.'">'.$lista->cateNombre.'</option>'; 
    
      // y con este intento mostrar la categoria que tiene el producto       
     echo '<option value="'. $lista->idCategoria.'" '. (($sel == $lista->idCategoria) ? 'selected="selected"':"").' >'.$lista->cateNombre.'</option>';
            
            }
    
          }else{ echo "no existe";} ?>
    ?>
```

pero no me esta mostrando nada

Comment: Me queda claro lo que quieres, pero, ¿del código que proporcionaste en dónde está el error? Porque yo estoy viendo que en efecto esttás haciendo una validación para poner la opción como selected

Comment: hola @FernandoTorres gracias por responder es precisamente hay donde esta el error.  En el código que esta comentado me muestra todas las categorías pero donde hago la validación no me la coloca como selected

Comment: Vale, vale. ¿Estás seguro que `$lista->idCategoria` en cada vuelta tiene un valor? Para poder validarlo te recomendaría imprimir en cada vuelta del `while` un `gettype($lista->idCategoria)` incluso para poder ver el tipo de dato que te regresa y así poder hacer la respectiva validación

Comment: si seguro con este codigo `echo '<option value="'.$lista->idCategoria.'">'.$lista->cateNombre.'</option>';` muestra todas las categorias con su idCategoria pero cuando le implemento la condicional no me funciona

Comment: Qué raro entonces. Te recomendaría hacer un Cast a los tipos de dato que validas en tu condición y separarlo, es decir, algo como:  `if ( intval($list->idCategoria) === $sel ) { echo "<option value="{$list->idCategoria}" selected>{$list->cateNombre}</option>"; } else { echo "<option value="{$list->idCategoria}">{$list->cateNombre}</option>"; }` Por otra parte, es posible que tengas varias categorías con el mismo id, y al haber más de un `<option>` con `selected` puede causar conflicto y no seleccionar ninguno de la lista

Comment: Cuando algo esté fallando, depura y agrega dicha depuración a la pregunta. En este caso es fundamental conocer lo que hay en `$lista` ,  por tanto, pon un `var_dump($lista);` dentro del `while` analiza esa salida y quizá te darás cuenta de cuál es el problema. Si no lo encuentras, compártenos esa salida agregándola a la pregunta y podremos ayudarte mejor.